# VS2015 CodeLens is missing

Tags: visual-studio, codelens

Somehow CodeLens doesn't work correctly. It only shows -references. It was working fine before.

I checked the  Options -> Text Editor -> All Language -> CodeLens

All options are checked.

Anyone see this before ? Thanks

Comment: Do you use Typescript in your solution? I have the same problem and I read somewhere that Typescript could be the problem and that the CodeLens teams was looking into it (in august 2015)

Comment: I do have Typescript. But I have two projects. Only one of them has this situation.

Comment: I you haven't already, install TypeScript 1.6.3 and see if it helps

Comment: Too bad, I am on typescript 1.6.3 already.

Comment: I think I solved my problem today. I had circular project references in my solution (A->B->A). I moved classes in project A needed by both project A and project B into a new project C. A->B, A->C and B->C. Circular project references was gone, and CodeLens started to work again. Check if you have any circular project references in your solution

Comment: not my case. How is that possible in the first place anyway ? I thought VS would stop you before you add it.

Comment: Having any typescript projects in your solution is enough to trigger this issue. It existed in Vs2015 RTM. We (my team) very recently fixed this problem. The fix should be available in the next preview of Vs update. Hope that helps.

Comment: oh yeah ! Thank you @balajikris I really think this feature is awesome !

Comment: @balajikris FYI it is fixed after update 1 RC1

Comment: @maxisam - great! good to know it works now. thanks for getting back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**: It is fixed after I upgrade to vs2015 update 1 RC1

It turns out it is conflicted with another extension I installed called "Go To Implementation".

It happens again. This time I have no clue. Anyone ?

Answer (score 3):

In my case the conflict was with "[Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)"

After disable "Productivity Power Tools" extension Codelens  back to work

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well.  It turned out to be my TFS connection in Visual Studio was incorrect or corrupted after upgrading to VS 2015 from 2012.  The Team Foundation Server URL had the Project Collection missing and I was getting a "One or more errors has occurred." when going to Manage Connections under Team Explorer.

To fix it:

- Open the Team Explorer navigation dropdown and Select Projects and My Team -> Manage Connections.
- Click the Manage Connections dropdown and Select Connect to Team Project.
- Add server if not populated and check off appropriate Team Collection and Team Project
- Click Connect and Visual Studio reconnected with the fixed/updated URL. *My server was already populated and appropriate Team Project checked, so I just clicked Connect.*

After I followed those steps CodeLens TFS information was showing up.